# My UK visitor visa got refused, Should I reapply?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, proof-provenance-of-funds

[image]

I got this refusal letter:
1- It seems to me the ECO has not understood my blocking account status that is 8740 Euros. 
2- I am a student in Germany, I have obtained the money in both my blocked account and my personal current account in Iraq where I worked for 5 years. 
3- I am fully sponsored by my fiancee, but he has ignored this and the evidences with it.
What shall I do? It is really important to me to visit her for these three weeks, because here in Germany I live in a shared flat. It is not possible for her to come and live with me here. if I reapply explaining my financial situation, do I have a chance of getting it?

I appreciate your kind responses.

Comment: You’re unlikely to be successful with another application. He’s seeing that your expenditure is more than your income and conveniently ignoring your savings. Unless you have documentation to show the source of that big chunk of savings, forget about getting a visa. He’s getting you on funds parking and unknown Provence of funds. **Nobody can tell you your chance of getting the visa**. In my estimation your chances are slim.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying about a blocked account. If it's blocked (why? how? until when?) and you can't access it, then it's irrelevant for your application. Basically the ECO is telling you they don't understand how you are supporting yourself in Germany at the moment, so they don't think you have any reason to go back there.

Comment: The German government requires some international students to provide a blocked account as a proof of having enough funds to live in Germany. This blocked account is given back to the student on a monthly basis. i.e. I get 715 euros monthly from the stated blocked account. I did provide the statements, and they clearly show it.

Comment: @Ranj Did you explain how a blocking account works in your application/covering letter? There’s no such system in the UK, if you didn’t explicitly explain the ECO may well not have understood. Where does the figure of €342pm quoted by the ECO come from, if you receive €715? Did you state this in your application? If the funds are blocked and released to you monthly, how are they ‘available to you’ while in the UK? What does ‘fully sponsored by your fiancée’ mean - was she covering all your expenses/accommodation? Are you sure your application was clear and coherent from an ECO’s point of view?

Comment: @Traveller, No that was a mistake I did. I thought they would know what a blocked account is, since I provided the confirmation of the bank and the statements of the monthly money I had received from it until that moment. As for the €342, I receive this money from the Iraqi government as I am an employee at the university (currently on study leave but I still receive this amount and provided evidence). Yes she covers all the expenses and also provided all necessary documents. I believe it was clear and coherent apart from the blocking account that I assumed they would know.

Comment: the €715 comes from the blocked account, which was initially €8740. I mean, I am not allowed to take all the money together, but rather, they automatically transfer €715 into my current account each month. At the moment there is around €5000 still blocked.

Comment: @Ranj So for income you should have stated (and provided evidence for) €342 + €715 + any regular support from your fiancée, if you receive any. Doesn’t look like you explained your financial circumstances (and, possibly, the extent of your fiancée’s sponsorship) clearly. https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/589168/VAF1-guidance.pdf

Comment: You might want to explain that the "blocked account" as a *deposit* account required by the German government for living expenses.

Comment: @traveller I agree that I could have explained it better and in words too. Do you personally think if I reapply I stand a chance?

Comment: @mkennedy I should have done that. I will do so if I reapply. Thanks